# What is wrong in this Python code for Regularized Linear Regression?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I wrote code with numpy(theta, X is numpy array):

```
def CostRegFunction(X, y, theta, lambda_):
    m = len(X)
    # add bias unit
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((m,1)),X),1)

    H = np.dot(X,theta)

    J = (1 / (2 * m)) * (np.sum([(H[i] - y[i][0])**2 for i in range(len(H))])) + (lambda_ / (2 * m)) * np.sum(theta[1:]**2)

    grad_ = list()

    grad_.append((1 / m) * np.sum([(H[j] - y[j][0]) for j in range(len(H))]))
    for i in range(len(theta)-1):
        grad_.append((1 / m) * np.sum([(H[j] - y[j]) * X[j][i+1] for j in range(len(H))]) + (lambda_ / m) * theta[i+1])

    return J, grad_



def TrainLinearReg(X, y, theta, lambda_, alpha, iter):

    JHistory = list()
    for i in range(iter):
        J, grad = CostRegFunction(X, y, theta, Lambda_)
        JHistory.append(J)
        for j in range(len(theta)):
            theta[j] = theta[j] - alpha * grad[j]

    return theta, JHistory

Theta, JH = TrainLinearReg(X, y, th, Lambda_, 0.01, 50)
```

But when I try learn theta this code gives me a realy huge grow of theta and value of J.
For example first iteration grad = [-15.12452, 598.435436] - it is correct. J is 303.3255
2nd iteration - grad = [10.23566,-3646.2345] J = 7924
and so on J grows faster and faster but on idea of LR it must be lower.

But if I use Normal Linear Equation in gives me a good Theta.

What is wrong in that code?

Comment: Did you check with various `alpha` values?

Comment: Yes.. I tried earlier alpha = 0.001 but it gave me constant J on each iteration = 141. But I try varios values now and it gave me corect answer!(alpha = 0.001) I'm wondering, really. Perhaps I find a mistake and fix it but doesn't try varios alpha no more. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is what in your regression functions? what is X,Y,theta etc? and what is the shape of each of the things? because i think somehow with those for j in range(len(... statements, you complicate a lot of things

Answer (score 4):

### numpy version

. edited on Oct 17th

I rewrote parts of the code using numpy libraries.

All vectors are now columns numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy as dc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

_norm = np.linalg.norm    

def CostRegFunction(X, y, theta, lambda_):
    m = len(X)
    H = np.dot(X,theta)
    J = (1 / (2 * m)) * _norm(H-y)**2 + (lambda_ / (2 * m)) * _normal(theta[1:])**2
    grad_ = np.array(sum(H-y)/m,ndmin=2).T
    for i in range(theta.shape[0]-1):
        grad_=np.concatenate((grad_,np.array(sum((H-y)*np.array(X[:,1],ndmin=2).T)/m + (lambda_/m) * theta[i+1],ndmin=2).T),0)
    return J, grad_

def TrainLinearReg(X, y, theta, lambda_, alpha, iter):
    JHistory = list()
    # add bias unit -> it's better to do it here, before entering the loop
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((X.shape[0],1)),X),1)
    for i in range(iter):
        J, grad = CostRegFunction(X, y, theta, lambda_)
        JHistory.append(J)
        theta = theta -  alpha*grad
    return theta, JHistory
```

Then I generated a simple set of x-y polynomial data with white noise and fitted the polynom-equation using the `TrainLinearReg`function.

```
x = np.concatenate((np.array(np.linspace(0,10,100) + np.random.normal(0,0.01,100),ndmin=2).T,\
np.array(np.linspace(0,10,100)**2 + np.random.normal(0,0.01,100),ndmin=2).T),1)
y = 2 + -3*np.array(x[:,0],ndmin=2).T + np.random.normal(0,3,[100,1]) - 2*np.array(x[:,1],ndmin=2).T
th = np.array([1,2,3],ndmin=2).T
alpha = 0.001
lambda_ = 0.1
Theta, JH = TrainLinearReg(x, y, dc(th), lambda_, alpha, 10000)
```

What I get is the following.

```
plt.plot(x[:,0],y,'o',label='Original Data',alpha = 0.5)
x2 = np.linspace(0,10,10)
plt.plot(x2,Theta[0]+x2*Theta[1]+x2**2*Theta[2],'-',label='Fitted     Curve',lw=1.5,alpha=0.8,color='black')
plt.gca().set_xlabel('x')
plt.gca().set_ylabel('y')
plt.legend()

Output >> Theta = array([[ 1.29259285],
                         [-2.97763304],
                         [-1.98758321]])
```

[image]

I hope I have been of some help.

Best regards,
Gabriel